# libnodave communication with S7-1200

Tags: c++, communication, plc, libnodave, s7-1200

For a couple of days i've been trying to use libnodave as communication library to communicate with a S7-1200 PLC of Siemens(CPU 1214C). 
With the libnodave library there are a couple of things provided.
The Delphi application is working, the windows executable is working.

On the Vmware I'm running Linux and the precompiled binary of testISO_TCP is working.
Seems like i can use it, right?

```
daveInterface * di;
daveConnection * dc;
_daveOSserialType fds;
ds.rfd=openSocket(102, "192.168.0.1");
fds.wfd=fds.rfd;
if (fds.rfd>0) {
    di =daveNewInterface(fds,"IF1",0, daveProtoISOTCP, daveSpeed187k);
    daveSetTimeout(di,5000000);
    dc =daveNewConnection(di,0,0,1);  // insert your rack and slot here
    if (0==daveConnectPLC(dc)) 
    {
       printf("Connected..\n");
    }
}
```

But when i copy the source code 1:1 to my IDE (Eclipse) i get the following error message:

```
IF1 error in daveConnectPLC() step 1. retrying...IF1 error in daveConnectPLC() step 1. retrying...IF1 error in daveConnectPLC() step 1. retrying...Couldn't connect to PLC.
Please make sure you use the -2 option with a CP243 but not with CPs 343 or 443.
```

Seems like there is some error when connecting to the PLC. The following function generates this error:

> DaveConnectPLC(dc)

**Note that the rack and slot are unchanged when you compare it to the executed binary in Linux!**

Is someone able to help me to get it work on the Eclipse IDE? It's quite weird all the executables/binaries are working but when i want to execute it straight from IDE it's not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a similar problem that I am investigating now. Hopefully I will have an answer for you soon. In my case I had this working for over a year when suddenly after a routine rebuild of my libraries nothing worked anymore. My guess is that nodave is very sensitive to build flags.

Answer (score 1):

First fo all running on virtual is not the same as running on a real computer.
That it runs on Windows does not guarantee it runs under Linux despite the fact the source is the same and/or the same libraries are used.
Basically the precompiled program under Linux is the only proof that it will and can run.

Whenever I have issues in this area, I look with the compiler version used and compiler settings. Running code with debug option is notorious to corrupt code with hardware communication.

If you were not already using Wireshark, I would highlt recommend to use it. It is a perfect tool to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I created a program and precompiled it on Linux. Linux is running on the VMware so it's not giving any problems. When i use the same program running from Eclipse, it is not working. I think it's a problem with Eclipse but i'm not sure. I've checked the compiler version and they are both the samen. Running in debug mode made no difference. I have also been using wireshark, seems like i am able to ping the PLC, but it´s not sending any messages back.

Comment: Do you run the program in Eclipse or the result from a shell?
It can be that Eclipse is blocking.